# Consider missing object keys as null in JSON.net with JSON Path

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

My JSON looks like this sometime, which has `name` key missing in 2nd object. It may be any key in thousands of JSON file I read dynamically to extract fields required using JSON Path queries.

```
void Main()
{
    string jsonText = @"[
          {
            'rank': 1,
            'name': 'name 1',
            'year': '1991'
          },
          {
            'rank': 2,
            'year': '1992'
          },
          {
            'rank': 3,
            'name': 'name 3',
            'year': '1993'
          }
        ]";

    JToken json = JToken.Parse(jsonText);
    List<Fields> fields = new List<Fields>
    {   
        new Fields
        {
            name = "rank",
            path = "$.[*].rank",
            result = new List<string>()
        },
        new Fields
        {
            name = "name",
            path = "$.[*].name",
            result = new List<string>()
        },
        new Fields
        {
            name = "year",
            path = "$.[*].year",
            result = new List<string>()
        }
    };

    foreach(var field in fields)
    {
        var result = json.SelectTokens(field.path);
        foreach (var token in result)
        {           
            if (token is JObject || token is JArray)
            {
                field.result.Add(token.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));
            }
            else
            {
                field.result.Add(token.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    fields.Dump();
}

public class Fields
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public List<string> result {get; set;}
}
```

Which results in below incorrect table as the "name 3" moved one row up on 2nd row. While it should be on 3rd row and the 2nd row should have null value.

[image: fields result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way (Updated to fix trailing missing fields):

```
void Main()
{
    string jsonText = @"[
      {
        'rank': 1,
        'name': 'name 1',
        'year': '1991'
      },
      {
        'rank': 2,
        'year': '1992'
      },
      {
        'rank': 3,
        'name': 'name 3',
      }
    ]";

    JToken json = JToken.Parse(jsonText);
    List<Fields> fields = new List<Fields>
    {
        new Fields
        {
            name = "rank",
            path = "$.[*].rank",
            result = new List<string>()
        },
        new Fields
        {
            name = "name",
            path = "$.[*].name",
            result = new List<string>()
        },
        new Fields
        {
            name = "year",
            path = "$.[*].year",
            result = new List<string>()
        }
    };
    var max = json.SelectTokens("$.[*]").Count().Dump();
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        var result = json.SelectTokens(field.path);
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var token in result)
        {
            while(!token.Path.StartsWith($"[{index++}]"))
                field.result.Add(null);
            if (token is JObject || token is JArray)
            {
                field.result.Add(token.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));
            }
            else
            {
                field.result.Add(token.ToString());
            }
        }
        field.result.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0,max-result.Count()).Select(z=>(string)null));
    }
    fields.Dump();
}

public class Fields
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public List<string> result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting ! Don't we have any setting to treat missing keys as null in json.net built in? Because most the the NoSQL database produce json this way these days where the remove the key if it's value is null.

Comment: I removed `year` key from the last object to test and it doesn't add null in that case. What should I change to do that?

Comment: Well, you'd have to ask how many array elements there are and save it in a variable `max`, and then `field.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0,max-result.Count()).Select(z=>null));` after the inner foreach.