# Newtonsoft.Json - How to get null for missing leafs in SelectTokens

Tags: json.net

I'm looking for something similar to what is available here: https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

[Return null for missing leaf option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLZaF.png)

In this example the json path is `$.store.book[*].category`. I want to get all categories of all books in the store. But if for some reason a book does not have the 'category' property, I want to get a null on that position.

I'm trying to do that in Newtonsoft with `jobject.SelectTokens("arr[*].prop")`
But I only get the actual values and never a null in the middle if any of the items does not have that property.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dodbn3) is returning

```
[
  "Bob",
  "Joe"
]
```

But should return

```
[
  "Bob",
  null
  "Joe"
]
```

Is there any way to achieve this or would it be a new feature request in the github repo?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consider missing object keys as null in JSON.net with JSON Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445090/consider-missing-object-keys-as-null-in-json-net-with-json-path)

Comment: @PeterCsala I was looking to either being able to specify that nulls are wanted in the JSON Path expression or have this as an option in the SelectTokens method. If none are possible, that would be a possible workaround, yes. Thanks for finding it

Comment: Json.net does not have this functionality. The SelectTokens has an overload which anticipates a bool. But that flag is used to throw exception when no node is found under the specified jsonpath.

Comment: I submitted a feature request on github to add this as an option in `JsonSelectSettings` class which `SelectTokens` already receives in one of the overloads. Thanks!

Comment: You can leave an answer here where you point to the feature request.

Answer (score 0):

As of today this is not supported, so I opened a feature request on the package github: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2641